# Crawl Component 0 Stuck in Recovering Mode

Tags: search, crawling

The Admin and Query components both display a status of 'Online'.

[image: Search Topology]

WSS_WPG and WSS_ADMIN_WPG have access to the Index location.  The search account is in the WSS_WPG group.  The Search Service Account and Farm Account are both dbo on the Admin, CrawlStore, and PropertyStore databases.  I checked the PDF registry keys and they were correct.  The Search Service is started in 'Services on Server'.  The Search and Farm services are started on the services.msc window and running under the proper accounts.  Recreating the Service Application was ineffective.  Rebooting the Server was ineffective.  When I try to add a new Crawl Component, I get the error:

Errors were encountered during the configuration of the Search Service Application.

System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported. at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchConfigWizard.UpdateSearchApp() at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchConfigWizard.ProvisionSearchServiceApplication() at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchConfigurationJobDefinition.ExecuteTimerJob() at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAdministrationServiceJobDefinition.ExecuteAdminJob(Guid targetInstanceId) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTimerJobInvokeInternal.Invoke(SPJobDefinition jd, Guid targetInstanceId, Boolean isTimerService, Int32& result)

The only other error in the logs is as follows:

The Search Server Wizard welcome page for site '[Central Admin URL]' does not exist in the root folder.

Does anyone have a fix for this issue?

Comment: Are you trying to add the crawl component on a different server other than PWIRISK2010 ? Additionally please share the  ULS logs

Comment: I am not trying to add it to another server, there is only one WFE/App in the farm. The error I specified was from the ULS logs.

Comment: Is the farm running on WORKGROUP mode or is it joined to a Domain ? Additionally, please share the corresponding windows event logs as well with the description field.

Comment: The farm is joined to a domain.  All the accounts are domain accounts.  The errors are the same in the Event Log and the ULS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Managed Metadata Service or User Profile Service was causing the Timer Service to restart every minute.  That was preventing the Search Service from provisioning correctly.  I stopped the Managed Metadata Service, User Profile Sync Service and User Profile Service.  When I restarted the services, the Timer Service returned to normal and I could create the search service application.